# how to specify to get latest SNAPSHOT version on gradle compile statement

Tags: gradle, jar, compilation, artifactory, snapshot

I cannot seem to get the latest snapshot version of my artifactory jar file no matter what I try. This compile statement works in my build.gradle:

compile(group: 'etd.blue-redis', name: 'blue-redis', version: '1.0.1', ext: '4.SNAPSHOT.jar')

but I cannot seem to use any wildcards to get the latest version.

I have tried the following and in every case nothing gets downloaded:

```
compile(group: 'etd.blue-redis', name: 'blue-redis', version: '+')

compile(group: 'etd.blue-redis', name: 'blue-redis', version: '1.0.1', ext: '+.SNAPSHOT.jar')

compile(group: 'etd.blue-redis', name: 'blue-redis', version: '1.0.1', ext: '+')

It looks like this in Artifactory:
>  etd
>>   blue-redis/blue-redis   
>>>   1.0.1
>>>>  blue-redis-1.0.1.4.SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Ultimately my preference is to be able to get the latest snapshot from a particular version

Answer (score 1):

There are different things at play here:

- The version part of your dependency is `1.0.1.4.SNAPSHOT`. Your split attempts are invalid. You should not need to specify `ext` at all.
- Gradle auto detects snapshot versions by looking for `-SNAPSHOT` which is the Maven convention. If your library uses `.SNAPSHOT` you may need to tell Gradle this is [a `changing` library](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:declaring_dependency_with_changing_version) explicitly.
- By default Gradle caches changing versions for 24h. If that's too long for your build, the value can be [customized](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/troubleshooting_dependency_resolution.html#sec:controlling_dependency_caching_programmatically) by setting `resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor`.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Gradle. Does your answer mean that I should declare my version as 1.0.1.+.SNAPSHOT if I want the latest snapshot version or just 1.0.1.+ with a changing policy? Every time I see an actual build.gradle file I only see compile or testCompile statements but when I look at the Gradle docs they don't usually have them, it is always other statements, like implementation. Maybe I am trying to oversimplify these dependencies?

Comment: Any version that ends in `-SNAPSHOT` will by default behave as a changing version. So if you want the latest snapshot of `org:foo:1.1-SNAPSHOT`, you only need to use that as the dependency coordinates: `implementation 'org:foo:1.1-SNAPSHOT'`. The map notation is not required for simple references. For the rest, I recommend going over the Gradle documentation, using the links I provided.

Comment: What Louis is saying is that your dependency should be `compile(group: 'etd.blue-redis', name: 'blue-redis', version: '1.0.1.4-SNAPSHOT')`. This should always get you the latest snapshot version of 1.0.1.4. You would not use version pattern wildcards with snapshot versions, rather if there are multiple "released" versions of an artifact your app is compatible with.